# (Javascript Recursion) Why is "value" increasing without increment code?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was studying Dynamic Programming in Javascript. I am a newbie of Javascript. I am really wondering why `value` is increasing even though I haven't made any conditions to increase `value`?

Here's the code.

```
const makeChange = value => {
    let coins = [1, 5, 10, 25];
    let newAmount;

    for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; ++i) {
        const coin = coins[i];
        console.log(`1. value: ${value}`);
        newAmount = value - coin;
        console.log(`2. value: ${value}`);
        if (newAmount >= 0) {
            console.log(`3. value: ${value}`);
            newMin = makeChange(newAmount);
            console.log(`4. value: ${value}`);
        }
        console.log(`5. value: ${value}`);
    }
};
```

In order to check output, I type `console.log(makeChange(2));`. In other words, `value` is 2.

Output is like below:

```
1. value: 2
2. value: 2
3. value: 2
1. value: 1
2. value: 1
3. value: 1
1. value: 0
2. value: 0
5. value: 0
1. value: 0
2. value: 0
5. value: 0
1. value: 0
2. value: 0
5. value: 0
1. value: 0
2. value: 0
5. value: 0
4. value: 1
5. value: 1
1. value: 1
2. value: 1
5. value: 1
1. value: 1
2. value: 1
5. value: 1
1. value: 1
2. value: 1
5. value: 1

4. value: 2
5. value: 2
1. value: 2
2. value: 2
5. value: 2
1. value: 2
2. value: 2
5. value: 2
1. value: 2
2. value: 2
5. value: 2
```

I can't understand why `value` increased from 1 to 2.

Comment: Every invocation of the function has it's own local `value`.

Comment: add a second argument `recursionDepth` and indent the `console.log("  ".repeat(recursionDepth), ...);` this may give you a better perspective on where you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's follow your example step by step:

1. makeChange(2) --> For in loop iterates only by '1', and invokes new function makeChange(1) and again for in loop iterates only by '1' and invokes new function makeChange(0) and here whole for loop has been iterated because `newAmount` is lower than 0. But your previous function makeChange(1) and makeChange(2) hadn't ended before makeChange(0) was invoked. So, makeChange(1) continue from `i=1` (because before stopped when `i=0`), makeChange(2) does the same.
2. Your `Call stack` looks as follows:

   ```
   makeChange(2) --> makeChange(1) --> makeChange(0) --> makeChange(1) --> makeChange(2) --> empty
                     makeChange(2)     makeChange(1)     makeChange(2)
                                       makeChange(2)
   ```
3. If you track values of `coin` amd 'newAmount' during function you can see what follows

   ```
   COIN: 1            //makeChange(2)
   NEW AMOUNT: 1      //makeChange(2) for in loop is pause on i = 1
   COIN: 1            //makeChange(1)
   NEW AMOUNT: 0      //makeChange(1) for in loop is pause on i = 1 
   COIN: 1            //makeChange(0) i = 0
   NEW AMOUNT: -1     //makeChange(0) i = 0
   COIN: 5            //makeChange(0) i = 1  
   NEW AMOUNT: -5     //makeChange(0) i = 1
   COIN: 10           //makeChange(0) i = 2
   NEW AMOUNT: -10    //makeChange(0) i = 2
   COIN: 25           //makeChange(0) i = 3
   NEW AMOUNT: -25    //makeChange(0) i = 3
   COIN: 5            //Here we back to makeChange(1) i = 1
   NEW AMOUNT: -4     //makeChange(1) i = 1
   COIN: 10           //makeChange(1) i = 2
   NEW AMOUNT: -9     //makeChange(1) i = 2
   COIN: 25           //makeChange(1) i = 3   
   NEW AMOUNT: -24    //makeChange(1) i = 3
   COIN: 5            //Here we back to makeChange(2) i = 1
   NEW AMOUNT: -3     //makeChange(2) i = 1
   COIN: 10           //makeChange(2) i = 2
   NEW AMOUNT: -8     //makeChange(2) i = 2
   COIN: 25           //makeChange(2) i = 3
   NEW AMOUNT: -23    //makeChange(2) i = 3
   ```

Comment: what does this have to do with the event loop? answer is otherwise good

Comment: In this example, the event loop does nothing, but I mentioned it because I think it's worth knowing the whole problem, not just the part of the call stack

Comment: So in your opinon what's the problem?

Comment: There isn't a problem. The event loop doesn't get fetched from until the engine is idle. Recursion is done without adding to the event loop so it does not idle the engine. Each recursive call has their own stack frame with their own version of `value`, `coins`, and `newAmount`. The console.log prints before and aftter the call **the same value** but in between them other calls print before and after too with their **same value**.

Comment: I'm wondering if the confusion is that `event loop` is being used in place of `control flow`.  I've seen that confusion before.